# Cassandra multiple column sorting design

Tags: cassandra

Assuming an object as following:

```
performance {
    userid,
    date,
    score1,
    score2,
    score3,
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to query `performance`s sorted on either of the score fields. Should I create different tables for each `score` field as compound key or is there a better way to do this?

I hesitate to duplicate `performance` objects for each `score` field, as there may be many `score` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *performace* table, you could consider to create secondary indexes on *score1*, *score2* and *score3*. However, Cassandra's built-in secondary indexes are best on a column family having many rows that contain the indexed value. So, you have to balance your use case, avoid to use secondary indexes to query a huge volume of records for a small number of results. *In the purpose of sorting, this is not a good solution.*

In best practice, using roughly one table per query pattern is recommended. Data duplication is fine. It also helps to identify the most frequent query patterns and isolate the less frequent. Some queries might be executed only a few thousand times, while others a billion times. Also consider which queries are sensitive to latency and which are not. It is recommended to think and balance two high-level rules while modelling: spreading data evenly around cluster and minimising the number of partitions read.

Please see also: [Basic Rules of Cassandra Data Modeling](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look into secondary index solution, as I don't know how it works in cassandra. However, I like yor point on being able to see frequency of queries.

Comment: a high cardinality thing like "score" would probably perform poorly as a secondary index

Comment: @ChrisLohfink, I agree with you. I have edited my answer according to your comment. Thanks :)

Comment: Secondary indexes are useless if you want to sort by `score2` independently of `score1`. The way Cassandra works is by aggregating your columns into one row key (as it was called in the Thrift interface.) The result is that all your rows are sorted as in `ORDER BY score1, score2, score3, score4 ...` and that does not give you a way to do `ORDER BY score2` with just that one column.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem . and to solve it I duplicated the tables . this because for me it was necessary that in the where clause I could write `where ... and SCORE1 > 0 and SCORE1 < 100` . if you instead need only to use the equality operator , you can try to create an index , without duplicating the table .

if you need to sort the results based on those three columns at once then you can  create the table with `WITH CLUSTERING WITH ORDER BY ( score1 DESC,score2 DESC,score3 DESC);` and declare as clustering column, columns for which you want to order

Comment: sorry, perhaps before I did not understand your question , you need to sort the results based on those three columns at once ? because if yes then you create the table with "WITH CLUSTERING WITH ORDER BY ( score1 DESC,score2 DESC,score3 DESC) ;" and declare as clustering column columns for which you want to order .